# Div(Custom Cursor) is not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a custom cursor(circle as cursor). But the div is not visible however it is translating but is not visible.

HTML CODE

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="cursor">
        
      <!-- <svg height="100" width="100">
        <circle cx="15%" cy="15%" r="12%" stroke-width="0"></circle>
          </svg> -->
    </div> 
      <div class="header">
        <div class="menu-wrapper">
          <div class="menu-stroke"></div>
          <div class="menu-stroke"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
          <a>
            <img 
              src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60ec058b2e9d9a78efb4e45b/60f9757ec552987c5e48622c_logo.svg"
              width="26"
              height="36"
            />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <span class="contact-head">CONTACT</span>
            <img 
              src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/60ec058b2e9d9a78efb4e45b/60f04597b1bddea37f0be3c5_small-link.svg"
              width= "26"
              height="26"
            />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-heading-wrapper">
      <div class="heading-slider">
        <div class="head-line-1">
          <h1 class="head-h1 mb-0">Directrice Artistique Jr,</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="head-line-2">
          <h1 class="head-h1">UX & UI designeuse</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="head-desc">
          <h5 class="desc-content">Je crée des expériences digitales au service de l'utilisateur·rice.</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #fff5f0;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document?.body?.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

function onMouseMove(e) {
  TweenMax.to(cursor, 0, {
    x: e.pageX,
    y: e.pageY
  })
}
```

This picture is to show that div has height and width and it is also translating but it is not visible

Comment: What is `TweenMax`? Is it the same as or part of [GSAP](/tags/gsap/info)? If so, please [edit] your post and include that tag.

Comment: Also you have the `svg` inside the `.cursor` element commented out.